# query api response for content

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I have a create method in my `ModelViewSet` and after validating and cleaning the serializer I'm making a post request using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) library.

```
def create(self, request):
    serializer = MySerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

        # post to remote server
        response = requests.post(
            url='{}/server'.format(settings.URL),
            json=do_some_cleaning(serializer.data)
        )
        logger.debug('response from server >>>>=%s', response.json)
        return Response({'response': response}, status=response.status_code, data=response.json)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I need to check my response get the `id` and store it in the object, or if it's not there need to query it and check do i have it, I need this `id` so I can work on the `PUT` method.
Can someone please explain me how can I achieve this.

Comment: You need call the json method to get response in json format like this `response.json()`

Comment: Where are you stuck ? What error are you getting ?

Comment: hm, well I'm stuck with the whole idea of how to do it, ok so I can return response.json() which I'm doing, the just iterate over it, how do I store it on the object?

Comment: Can you post your response structure ? In which object and in which you want to update that ? What PUT method are you talking about ?

Comment: no, this is post, the response is just a json with some data and the id inside it, I want to get that id store it in the object and use it later for put method, so json can be `{'id':'214124', .....}`

Comment: object.update(fieldname=response.json()["id"])

Comment: aham, ok, so can you construct and answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the json function to get response in json format. Something like

```
response = response.json()
```

Then you can fetch `id` from it like you would do from a `dict` object. Something like

```
id = response["id"]
```

Then you can update the same in your object. Like

```
object.field_name = id
object.save()
```